# Can I determine the brand and model of the joystick using GLFW?

Tags: java, c++, lwjgl, glfw

I check on **macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G87**) with lwjgl 3.2.3. I can definitely determine the name by `glfwGetJoystickName` and GUID by `glfwGetJoystickGUID`. For example, for my **Xbox Elite 2** (version 2!) connected via bluetooth such results:

- GUID: `030000005e040000050b000003090000`
- name: `Xbox Elite Wireless Controller`

In this case `glfwGetGamepadName` returns `null`.

For example, for my **Dualshock 4** connected via usb name is `Wireless Controller`.

This information is not enough for me. Are there any ways to find out more precisely the brand and model of the joystick using GLFW or LWJGL? I would be grateful if you suggest an option how to get this kind of information in another way.

Answer (score 0):

The [joystick input guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#joystick) points to [SDL_GameControllerDB](https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB).
This file maps GUIDs to different human names, along with mappings of general buttons to Xbox buttons. You could use that as a basis to see which buttons are present, or just use the file as-is and pretend the user has an Xbox gamepad.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help me. A successful call to glfwUpdateGamepadMappings did not change the situation. And GLFW reacts differently to every joystick. I launched the same program on Windows 10 and began to get non-empty speaking names by glfwGetGamepadName. For example, on dualshock 4 glfwGetGamepadName answered `PS4 Controller` (both on a wire and without). I'll try to understand why glfwGetGamepadName is silent on macOS (joysticks work because I use them in macOS Steam games successfully).